# How to create an asynchronous function to request data in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, request

I created the dataAllMovies.js file that contains the movie data. I want to get the data that is in the dataAllMovies.js file using an asynchronous function, however, the way I did it is wrong.

dataAllMovies.js

```
const id = Date.now();
export const dataAllMovies = {
    movies: [
        {
            id: id,
            title: "Capitão Fantástico",
            overview: "Nas florestas do estado de Washington, um pai cria seus seis filhos longe da civilização, em uma rígida rotina de aventuras. Ele é forçado a deixar o isolamento e leva sua família para encarar o mundo, desafiando sua ideia do que significa ser pai.",
            poster: require('./assets/img/capitao-fantastico.png'),
            watched: true,
            nota: []
        },
        {
            id: id,
            title: "Shrek",
            overview: "Para resgatar uma princesa das garras de um dragão que cospe fogo, o ogro Shrek se une a um companheiro improvável: um burro brincalhão.",
            poster: require('./assets/img/shrek.png'),
            watched: false,
            nota: []
        },
        {
            id: id,
            title: "Hoje Eu Quero Voltar Sozinho",
            overview: "Um novo colega de sala transforma a vida do estudante Leonardo, que também é cego, e complica sua amizade com sua melhor amiga",
            poster: require('./assets/img/hoje-eu-quero-voltar-sozinho.png'),
            watched: false,
            nota: []
        },
        {
            id: id,
            title: "Um Sonho de Liberdade",
            overview: "Condenado pelo assassinato da esposa e do amante dela, um banqueiro se apega à esperança e à amizade com um detento chamado Red para sobreviver à prisão.",
            poster: require('./assets/img/um-sonho-de-liberdade.png'),
            watched: false,
            nota: []
        },
        {
            id: id,
            title: "Que Horas Ela Volta",
            overview: "Val é a fiel empregada doméstica de uma família rica. Mas a chegada de sua filha gera tensão na casa e faz com que ela comece a questionar esse papel.",
            poster: require('./assets/img/que-horas-ela-volta.png'),
            watched: false,
            nota: []
        },
    ]
};
```

**Print the code in VsCode**
[image]

**Function to get data from dataAllMovies.js**
[image]

Please, can someone help me. How do I get data from dataAllMovies with async/await?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it has no effect is because, getAllMovies is not a promise to be awaited! One good way to find this is to click on ctrl + click on the method and check its type definitions.

You can do this and it will work

```js
const getAllMovies = () => {
  return dataAllMovies.movies
}

const getDestaques = async () => {
  const results = getAllMovies()
  return results
}
```

More about Promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Now from the docs above I have re-written it like so:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([])


const getAllMovies = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(dataAllMovies.movies)
  }, 300)
})

const getDestaques = async () => {
    // movies is whatever was passed in the resolve(...) function above
  const results = await getAllMovies.then(movies =>  setData(movies)).catch(error => {console.log(error)})
  return results
}
```

This will resolve `dataAllMovies.movies` after 300MS I haven't properly tested it so may need some tweaking but feel this will give you a good start.